# SSIS: Oracle Multiple rows to one column output without STRAGG

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, ssis

Looking to generate a comma separated list of languages when the ID is the same.

Table 1:

```
ID | LangID
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    3
2    4
3    1
```

Table 2:

```
ID | Language
1    English
2    Spanish
3    French
4    German
```

Want to generate results that look like:

```
ID | Languages
1    English, Spanish, French
2    French, German
3    English
```

Things I have tried:

Stragg - SSIS gives me "Invalid Identifier"

SYS_Connect_By_Path - Can't figure out how to join the ids to convert to the string languages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various ways to perform string aggregation to produce a comma separated list - see [this link for more details](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php).  Based on the example in the link, try:

```
SELECT x.id,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(x.language,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS employees
  FROM (SELECT a.id,
               b.language,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.language) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.language) -1 AS prev
          FROM TABLE_1 a
          JOIN TABLE_2 b ON b.id = a.langid) x
GROUP BY x.id
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND x.id = PRIOR x.id
START WITH curr = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

For 11g, check out the [listagg function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm)

```
select t1.id, listagg(t2.language, ', ') within group (order by t2.language)
from t1, t2
where t1.langId = t2.id
group by t1.id;
```