# SQL Getting Non-Repeating Values [Oracle SQL*Plus]

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a  table(order_t) that contains CustomerIDs and SalespersonIDs and I want to display SalespersonIDs with all the CustomerIDs associated with them.

I tried using SELECT DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT salespersonid, customerid
FROM order_t;
```

But that will repeat salespersonids.

Here is a table sample

```
salespersonid   customerid
--------------- ---------------
15              1
15              2
15              3
16              4
16              5
17              6
```

And I want to get this dataset as the result

```
salespersonid   customerid
--------------- ---------------
15              1
                2
                3
16              4
                5
17              6
18              4
                5
                9
```

This worked perfectly

```
BREAK ON sid
SELECT DISTINCT salespersonid sid, customerid cid
FROM ORDER_T
ORDER BY salespersonid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL*Plus, you would do the following:

```
SQL> BREAK ON sid

SQL> SELECT salespersonid sid, customerid cid
       FROM order_t
      ORDER BY salespersonid;
```

Should give you output that looks something like this (untested):

```
SID     CID
-----   ------
    1        1
             2
             3
    2        1
             7
    3        1
...
```

EDIT:

If you wanted a single row for each salespersonid, see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104527/ssis-oracle-multiple-rows-to-one-column-output-without-stragg) on how to do that. It's not trivial to do.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT will return the non-repeated combination of salespersonid and customerid.

In other words it can return same salespersonid but with different customerid.

e.g. 
1,1
1,2
1,3 ...

but it wont return 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3  again