# merging rows into 1 column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with 2 columns

```
Input
Col 1 ---- Col 2
1     ---- aaaa  
1     ---- bbbb
1     ---- cccc
2     ---- dddd
2     ---- eeee
2     ---- ffff
2     ---- gggg

Output

Col 1 ---- Col 2
1     ---- aaaabbbbcccc
2     ---- ddddeeeeffffgggg
```

I was thinking of doing several self joins, but doesnt seem efficient. Any ideas on how the sql has to be written?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSIS: Oracle Multiple rows to one column output without STRAGG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104527/ssis-oracle-multiple-rows-to-one-column-output-without-stragg), among others

Comment: Should't be closed. Above duplicate is little complex with normalized form.

Comment: why all the stragg questions lately?  is everyone in the same class or something? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll bite.  Instead of stragg, try listagg (in 11.2):

```
create table tst1
(
pid number,
val varchar2(10)
);


insert into tst1 values(1, 'Rec1');
insert into tst1 values(1, 'Rec2');
insert into tst1 values(1, 'Rec3');
insert into tst1 values(2, 'Rec1');
insert into tst1 values(2, 'Rec2');
commit;


select pid, listagg(val, ':') within group(order by val) as "The List"
from tst1
group by pid;
```

And you get:

```
pid   The List
1     Rec1:Rec2:Rec3
2     Rec1:Rec2
```

If you change the order by to "order by val desc" you'd get

```
pid   The List
1     Rec3:Rec2:Rec1
2     Rec2:Rec1
```

Comment: The accepted answer in the question I think this duplicates has a link to a page with many possible solutions to this problem. LISTAGG in 11g is one of them. Plus, the link is for ways to do this *without* STRAGG.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that will work in **Oracle 9i and up.**

```
create table foo (
  key_column number,
  val_column varchar2(4)
);

insert into foo values (1, 'aaaa');
insert into foo values (1, 'bbbb');
insert into foo values (1, 'cccc');
insert into foo values (2, 'dddd');
insert into foo values (2, 'eeee');
insert into foo values (2, 'ffff');
insert into foo values (2, 'gggg');


    select key_column
         , replace(max(sys_connect_by_path(val_column, ',')), ',') combined
      from (select key_column
                 , val_column
                 , row_number() over (partition by key_column order by val_column) cur
                 , row_number() over (partition by key_column order by val_column) - 1 prev
              from foo) foo
  group by key_column 
connect by prior cur = prev and prior key_column = key_column
start with cur = 1;

   key_column | val_column
  --------------------------
            1 | aaaabbbbcccc
            2 | ddddeeeeffffgggg
```